# Can Hibernate batch db queries for collection misses in the second level cache?

Tags: java, hibernate

For Hibernate 3.5.4, let's say I have a hibernate entity defined like this:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Team {

    @Id
    protected Long id;
    protected List<Player> players;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Player.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @NotFound(action= NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize(size = 50)

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return this.players;
    }

    public List<Player> setPlayers(List<Player> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }

    // More stuff

}
```

And then I have a Player entity defined as you might expect it to be. Logically, this creates three second level object caches:

- Team
- Team.players
- Player

I've found that if the Team.players cache is disabled or empty for the queried Team, Hibernate will make a batch request to the database where it retrieves all Players for a team with one query (doing a lookup of player.team_id = Team.Id). However, if the Team.players cache contains cached associations between a Team and a list of players, and those Player objects are absent from the Player cache, Hibernate will retrieve each of the Player objects **one at a time** by Player.Id with separate database queries. *Is there any way to get Hibernate to retrieve these collection field object cache misses in a batch?*

I've tried setting values for the following parameters, but they don't seem to impact this behavior:

- default_batch_fetch_size
- jdbc.batch_versioned_data
- jdbc.batch_size
- jdbc.fetch_size

I've also tried EAGER fetching instead of LAZY.

This hibernate forum post from 2008 alludes to this problem (https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=983649) but I haven't turned up any solutions. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

Build a `Collection<Long>` (assuming that's your player id type).  Iterate through the team's player list, checking the player object with `Hibernate.isInitialized(player)`.  If it's false, add the id to the collection.  This is assuming your `@Id` is on they player's id getter (not the field), so you can get the id from the player proxy without going to DB.

If you're using Java EE 6: instead of `Hibernate.isInitialized(player)`, try `em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().isLoaded(player)`.  This is preferred for container independence.

When you've got the list check if it's not empty.  If it's not empty, run a query:

```
SELECT p
JOIN Player p
WHERE p.id IN (:idList)
```

Setting the `idList` parameter with your `Collection<Long>`

Just run `query.getResultList()`; don't bother storing the query result anywhere.  This will materialize any proxies that were previously loaded from the team collection.

Comment: Hmm, this makes sense but I was kind of hoping for an annotation or config parameter solution rather than having to modify the various places across my code base where I happened to be using a collection... or even a way this could be baked directly into the getter of the collection would be nice. Any thoughts on if that is possible? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't think of any annotations to address that, but I'm not very familiar with those proprietary to Hiberate.  This is the only solution I could find when addressing 2nd level "woodpeckering".  Personally, I've only applied 2nd level caching to entities where I was willing to hold every single one in the cache... security access entities for instance.  If you are content to store every player you have (and ever will have), I would set your cache to be big enough and never expire, and the problem would go away.